# Adding follow-up notes to a question using comments

Tags: discussion, edits, comments, deleted-comments

I'm asking questions about quite specific topics, and recently adjusted a question I made to reflect my own code analysis and research results. I originally did a follow-up to it as comments, and because the original question was edited, the comments are no longer valid, so I deleted them. I still haven't come to a solution to the issue, so the question is not a moving target of any sort.

Yet I was wondering... Is practice valid? Do too many deleted comments get some sort of ban, like a parallel with question and comment bans? Or are the number of editions a question can get limited somehow?

Comment: If people are having a discussion in the comments, they'll usually be prompted to go to the chat room for a better medium of communicating.

Comment: It's actually quite good to delete your own obsolete comments. I frequently delete mine or flag those of others for deletion if they no longer apply to the  situation because of edits. It cleans up noise and clutter. I've never encountered any difficulty for doing so. You should be aware that moderators can still see deleted comments, however - if a comment is flagged because it's inappropriate and then the poster deletes it, a moderator can still access the comment. (I'm in no way implying you would do such a thing; I'm just pointing it out. I've run across some new users who were not aware.)

Comment: IMHO it's generally better to include the follow up information in the question itself, interspersed by "EDIT", "EDIT2" etc.

Comment: I agree with @Steve. Except for the "EDITn" bit - that's just insane, never do that.

Comment: What's wrong with EDITn? Edit: Oh yeah, it's annoying. Edit2: Isn't there a post edit history thing or something? Edit3: It feels I'm talking to myself.

Comment: No one ever looks at post histories. It's relevant to include the EDITn if people are commenting in between, so you can kind of see the back-and-forth.